# Xamarin Forms Lottie no muestra animación en iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

En Xamarin.Forms intento agregar una animación con el paquete nuget **Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie**, me funciona en Android pero en iOS me lanza una excepción:

```
An error occurred: 'Could not create an native instance of the type 'Airbnb.Lottie.LOTAnimationView': the native class hasn't been loaded.
```

Revisé la documentación de Lottie, además de los issues pero no he logrado solucionarlo.

La versión de Lottie es **4.1.0** y la de Xamarin es **5.0.0.2196**

Este es mi xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <lottie:AnimationView
                Animation="Resources.Animations.animation.json"
                AnimationSource="EmbeddedResource"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```